# Node.js : How to enable non strict or ECMASCRIPT3 in V8 engine?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, node.js, v8

I believe V8  underlying Node.js supports strict mode or ES5 by default.

Can we enable non strict or ECMASCRIPT 3 in V8 engine?

almost 100% of ES5 features are available in Chrome (V8) see [compatibility table](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/) .

But some developers(including me) are still comfortable with ES3, can we have that option?

Comment: Strict mode is not enabled by default. Also is there a 'real' reason you want to use ES3? Your ES3 work should also run using a ES5 interpreter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just don't include the string `"use strict"` in your code. V8 supports strict mode, it doesn't  use it unless you tell it to (i.e. it follows the ES5 specification).

Compare the following scripts:

Input:

```
foo = "Hello";
console.log(foo);
```

Output:

```
quentin@workstation:tmp # node test.js
Hello
```

and

Input:

```
"use strict";
foo = "Hello";
console.log(foo);
```

Output:

```
quentin@workstation:tmp # node test.js

node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
ReferenceError: foo is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/quentin/tmp/test.js:2:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:432:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:450:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:351:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Array.0 (module.js:470:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:40)
```

Comment: is it? i think by default V8 uses strict, no need to mention explicitly "use strict".